# How to know if the winform has stopped functioning/responding

Tags: c#, winforms

I made a Skype Bot that will send messages back to the person depending on what they say, and on the form there is Label1 that says Skype Bot is: Running but i want to add code that changes the text to Skype Bot is: Not Running if it stops responding/working/whatever, but I dont know how to write/know if it stops working or not, I know how to have it change the text though, and under the Label1 there will be a restart button that reloads the form/process so it'll rerun.

Comment: If the winform stops running, I doubt anything will be able to update the GUI.

Comment: _"if it stops responding/working/whatever"_ -- if _what_ stops responding? If you want to change the label if the program itself (your question implies that the "Skype bot" is the same program as contains the `Form` and its `Label`), then how is the program going to change the label if it's not responding? If your program should indicate that some _other_ program is not responding, then that's simple: if you perform some action to which the other program should respond and it doesn't, then it's not responding. Otherwise, it is. Other than that, your question is far too broad to be useful on SO

Comment: If you want to check if an application is responding, you can get the process by name and check `Responding` property. But you should know you can't  check the responsiveness of your application using itself. To check responsiveness of your application  you need to write a simple light application to check responsiveness of your main application in reasonable schedules. For more information see the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33980572/3110834)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if the other application is running or responding you can [get the process by its name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z3w4xdc9(v=vs.110).aspx) and if found, then check [`Responding`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

But you should know you can't check the responsiveness of your application using itself. To check responsiveness of your own application you need to write a simple light application to check responsiveness of your main application in reasonable schedules.

```
var p = Process.GetProcessesByName("OtherApplication").FirstOrDefault();
if (p != null)
{
    if (p.Responding)
        MessageBox.Show("Responding");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Not Responding");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Not Running");
}
```

For more information you can see:

- [How to detect if an application has stopped responding by using Visual C#](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/304991)
- [How to: Determine If a Process Is Responding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aykwfbdh(v=vs.90).aspx)